# Porque no cargar las imagenes python con PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy realizando una interfaz con PyQt5. En QtDesigner  cargue una imagen, pero al momento de ejecutarlo no la muestra. Hice todo el procedimiento bien para cargar una imagen (genere un archivo qrc).

Les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Aquí esta mi código:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit,QMessageBox,QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from sympy import *
from Bisecciones import Bisecciones
from Gauss import Gauss
from Nr import Nr
from Jacobi import Jacobi
class VentanaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self) 
        loadUi("pantallaPrincipal.ui",self)
        #self.lista2.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.abrirVentanaGauss)
        self.lista2.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.printItem)
        self.lista1.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.Raices)   

app= QApplication(sys.argv)
main=VentanaPrincipal()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Bienvenido Edgar... puedes mostrarnos tu codigo??? sera mas facil darte una mano si tenemos algo de donde partir...

Comment: claro, disculpa. Listo

Comment: @EdgarTrejoGutierrez, donde estas cargando la imagen?

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez la cargo bien en QtDesigner, pero en el código ya no hago nada para cargarla, supongo que va implícito al cargar el .ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LISTO!
El archivo .qrc puede ser lo que Qt designer usa para conectarse a las imágenes. Sin embargo, cuando estoy cargando el archivo .ui en mi aplicación .py, tengo problemas para usar el archivo .qrc, así que en su lugar necesito crear una versión .py de .qrc.

Vaya al directorio en el que se encuentra .qrc usando el símbolo del sistema y escriba este comando. Tenga en cuenta que xz es exactamente lo que yo llamé "tuyo", que se puede llamar "cosa más".

pyrcc5 xz.qrc -o xz_rc.py

Luego, importe esto a su aplicación .py sin necesidad de agregar .py al final, ya que lo estamos importando como un módulo.

import xz_rc

Ahora su aplicación .py mostrará imágenes gracias a tener acceso a un formato que ahora puede comprender.